# Sending ZPL code to Zebra TLP2844 printer

Tags: php, label, zpl

```
$barcode_ZPL_code ="^XA 
     ^FWR 
    ^FO 425,450^A0,20,30^FH^FD_20TITTLE_20TITLE_2DTITLE^FS
     ^FO 380,450^A0,20,30^FH^FDDATE_3A18_2D03_2D2015^FS 
    ^FO 250,450^AD^BY2 ^BC,100,Y,N,N ^MD1    
    ^FH^FDUGTTGD_2D1_282_29_2DPSHAR_2DAMP22^FS
     ^XZ";
```

I got the above code to print barcode but I am not being able to send this code to my Zebra TLP 2844 printer via php. So please anyone

Comment: why I am getting minus here...???

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The Zebra TLP 2844 only speaks EPL language, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497397/zebra-lp2844-stopped-responding-to-zpl-commands-or-files).

Answer (score 0):

Is the printer networked and on the same LAN as the computer running the PHP code? If so, you could send via CURL and FTP to the printer's IP address. Otherwise you need to look at some alternative output method.